# Geoserver create user by rest in java manager

Tags: java, rest, geoserver

I want to create **new user** by rest in geoserver.
Also I want to do that by **java geoServer manager**.
But I can not found any api for do that.
If any api exists for do that?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [GeoServer REST API documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/rest/api/index.html) doesn't seem to show any support for adding new users.So it looks like you would need an enhancement to GeoServer and then GeoManager. Please read the [guidelines for enhancement requests](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer) before you proceed down that route.